# Error: no element in sequence. Rxjs onErrorResumeNext() and first()

Tags: angular, operators, angular8

**First of all**, I've googled lots of questions about **Error: no element in sequence**. To replace **first()** with **take(1)** can solve my problem, but for me it's a workaround, not a fix.

***I use Angular 8 in my project.***

**CODE**

```
loadResources(resources: LocalizeResources = null) {

    // some other codes...

    const urls = [
      `json/i18n-resources${this.locale ? '-' + this.locale : ''}.json`,
      'json/i18n-resources-en-GB.json',
      'json/i18n-resources.json'
    ]

    return onErrorResumeNext(
      urls.map(url => this.http.get<LocalizeResources>(url))
    ).pipe(
      first(),
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

In this function, I use **onErrorResumeNext()** to retrive data from back-end. It should retrive data according to **urls** one by one until it gets the first data(That is operator **first()** works.)

But somehow, it just use the first url **`json/i18n-resources${this.locale ? '-' + this.locale : ''}.json`**, and this url has no resource to return, then the error **Error: no element in sequence** is shown in console.

So why dosen't **onErrorResumeNext()** use the next two urls?
[image]

I have defined the resouce file in the back-end and I can get it with the second url. But **onErrorResumeNext()** just dosen't want to try it, it just stopped when the first url returns nothing.

**Replace first() with take(1) works, and I know it, But it's not the root cause, it's not a fix**  anyone can help?

Comment: And the problem only occurs in production environment, it works all fine with ng serve.